# Use of 'was' or 'were'

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I am confused in this sentence about the use of *was* or *were*.

> Basket after basket was/were filled with mangoes.

I think *was* is suitable.

Comment: Yes, it is, because the idiom refers to one basket at a time being filled.